# checkbox values not passed through JSON

Tags: php, json, checkbox

It was working fine. I'm just surprise to find all of a sudden, the checkbox values are not passed through in $_POST via json. I can't seem to understand why.
Hopefully someone could help me with this.Below is the checkbox in php.

```
$subjects_id= $row['subid'];

<td><input type="checkbox" name="sub['.$subjects_id.']" id="sub" value="">     </td>';
```

JSON

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".form").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
          "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
        );

        alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I'm sure there's no problem with JSON. But I doubt on my php for the checkbox. In the JSON key-value pairs, the checkbox is not passed although it's checked!

EDIT::

In my troubleshooting, I found that the below set of checkboxes actually conflicting with the above..So when they present the above checkboxes values not collected.When I comment out these, the above checkboxes' values collected!

```
<table class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 large-centered columns" class="availability">
                  <tr>
                      <th></th><th>Weekdays</th><th>Weekends</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="text-right">Morning<br/>(8am-12m)</td>
                      <td>
                         <div class="switch demo3">
                             <input type="checkbox" name="m_week" id="m_week">
                    <label><i></i></label>
             </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="switch demo3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="m_end" id="m_end">
                    <label><i></i></label>
              </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="text-right">Afternoon<br/>(12am-6m)</td>
                       <td>
                            <div class="switch demo3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="a_week" id="a_week">
                    <label><i></i></label>
                    </div>
                       </td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="switch demo3">
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="a_end" id="a_end">
                    <label><i></i></label>
                </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="text-right">Evening<br/>(6am-10m)</td>
                       <td>
                            <div class="switch demo3">
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="e_week" id="e_week">
                    <label><i></i></label>
                </div>
                       </td>
                      <td>
                           <div class="switch demo3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="e_end" id="e_end">
                    <label><i></i></label>
                </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON output? What's the php code in `response.php`?
Please notice that `id` attribute should be unique in the page, so if you're having multiple checkboxes in the mentioned format please make sure that have a different id value.

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I found something in troubleshooting!  The html consists of few section..The above is the section A, in section B there's anotehr group of checkboxes...So when I comment out these section B checkboxes,  them JSON collects the value of the section A checkboxes..WHen I enable it doesn't show.

Comment: @OfirBaruch, so I suspect some conflict between these two sets of checkboxes

Comment: None of the code you have here generates any JSON. (Presumably that is done by PHP you aren't showing us). You need to narrow down the problem (e.g. use the developer tools of your browser to find out what data is actually being sent to the server so you can determine if it is a problem with how you collect the data in JS or a problem with what you do with it in PHP) and then edit the question to focus on where the data is being lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes are sending true if checked, but nothing if unchecked. You can correct it by using :

```
$('checkbox').each(function(){
    $(this).val( checkbox[0].checked ? "true" : "false" );
});
```

checkbox.

This will set the value of the checkbox to "true" or "false" (value property is a string).